# Pause video, show a link, play another (part of the) video

Tags: jquery, html, video, interactive, popcornjs

I want to create a movie, where the visitor can change the history by taking decisions. I planned to play a sequence, than pause or stop the video using a CUE (if possible) and give two or three possibilities (for example - Go right or left?).Let's say we choose "go right". Now I need to play the video that displays the corresponding video for the answer " go right" and so on..
At the End the visitor would have his own history...
So far the idea...

How can I do this? I checked out the documentation from popcorn.js but I'm not sure it's what I need.

Does someone have an idea or maybe an example?

Is it even possible? :)

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible.
what you'd need is two things
1/ code to control the display of the buttons
2/ code to redirect the playhead

for 1 the easiest thing to do would be to add an eventlistener based on the timeupdated event which triggers the code you use to show buttons (and possibly stop the video from going too far). this would look up a table that lists what should happen at particular times based on the video currentTime attribute (eg from 00:50 to 00:55 show button "go left" and "go right". at 00:55 pause)

for 2 the button would simply need to pause the video, adjust the currentTime and then play